# What is the use of hasfile()? is required field validator is enough?

Tags: c#, asp.net

should i need to use Hasfile() while uploading file in asp.net if i use required field validater? What is the use of Hasfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RequiredFieldValidator` woudl be useful on the client side whereas [FileUpload.HasFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.hasfile.aspx) is useful on server side (Code behind).

[FileUpload.HasFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.hasfile.aspx)

> The HasFile property gets a value indicating **whether the FileUpload
>   control contains a file to upload**. Use this property to verify that
>   a file to upload exists before performing operations on the file. For
>   example, before calling the SaveAs method to save the file to disk,
>   use the HasFile property to verify that the file exists. If HasFile
>   returns true, call the SaveAs method. If it returns false, display a
>   message to the user indicating that the control does not contain a
>   file.

`RequiredFiledValidator` would only indicate if something has been entered in the control or not.

Its always a better practice to check at client as well as server end, The client's browser can have javascript disabled, in that case `RequiredFieldValidator` would fail to work.

Comment: so only client is enough ryt??

Comment: @SamSimon "Only client" is never enough. You should have both. Never underestimate the ability to circumvent things that only occur on the client

Comment: @SamSimon, no you should put check in place at both end, the client can have javascript disabled on the browser, in that case your RequiredFieldValidator would fail to work.

Comment: here i am saving path in database and file in separate folder, to maintain correctness which is the better way? save file first then store path in database or path in database first and then store file in folder? i want either both should happen or not.

Comment: @SamSimon, implement of kind of like transaction, simplest way would be to to put both operation in try catch, if any exception occur then undo the successful one